# Ubuntu 13.10 AdobeAIR application: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

Tags: adobe-air

I have installed AdobeAIR on 13.10, but am getting the following error messages when using:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

Has someone faced this issue. I looked at comment giving a possible resolution [here](http://jeffhendricks.net/?p=68#comment-538) , but that didn't help, as I already have those packages installed.

Basically to install AdobeAIR, being a 32-bit, I had to install various i386 packages:

```
libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
```

When I run the program as root, it opens up properly without errors. But that is not an option.

Could it be a problem that necessary modules are not getting loaded on non-root user's environment.

Comment: Adobe Air ceased support in all Linux platforms. Most problems you will face are most likely due unresolved bugs.